# Ember data: simplify post object with serialize and attrs hash with dashed jsonapi attributes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

Here is a simplified example. *Keep in mind the actual model is 20 fields and some computed properties*.


'order' model

```
shippingFirstName: DS.attr('string'),
shippingLastName: DS.attr('string'),
```

template (model passed in as newOrder)

```
<ul class="thing-list">
  <li class="thing first-name">
    <label class="field text" for="shippingFirstName">
      <div class="label">
        <span>First name</span>
      </div>
      {{input 
        id="shippingFirstName" 
        value=newOrder.shippingFirstName 
        placeholder="......."}}
    </label>
  </li>
...
```

posted data

```
data: {
  attributes: {
    shipping-first-name: 'sheriff',
    shipping-last-name: 'derek',
  },
  type: 'orders',
}
```

desired outcome

```
{
  shipping_to: {
    first_name: 'sheriff',
    last_name: 'derek',
  },
}
```

serializer for 'order' (what I would expect to work...)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

  serialize(snapshot, options) {
    let json = this._super(...arguments);
    json = json.data.attributes;

    console.log(json); // shows attributes as shipping-first-name

    json.shipping_to = {
      first_name: json.shippingFirstName,
      last_name: json.shippingLastName,
    };

    delete json.shippingFirstName;
    delete json.shippingLastName;

    return json;
  },

});
```

but the shipping_to properties to not appear in the post and the other values are in dash-case (JSON:API style)

The docs are great: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/models/customizing-serializers but the examples are not dashed keys.

When I fool around with the attrs hash, I can get things working - but it seems very arbitrary and/or I don't understand what is happening.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

  serialize(snapshot, options) {
    let json = this._super(...arguments);
    json = json.data.attributes;

    console.log(json);

    json.shipping_to = {
      first_name: json.whatever_thing_not_dashed,
      last_name: json.whateverThingCamel,
    };

    delete json.whatever_thing_not_dashed;
    delete json.whateverThingCamel;

    return json;
  },

  attrs: {
    shippingFirstName: 'whatever_thing_not_dashed',
    shippingLastName: 'whateverThingCamel',
  },

});
```

What am I missing? (The names on the backend aren't consistent enough to just turn camel to underscore across the board - and they are nested differently)

Comment: I would try to test if it is working when you are working directly with ```json.data.attributes```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all since your backend don't expect JSONAPI objects you should use another serializer like JSONSerializer

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_jsonserializer

this will remove the key "data" and "type", then you can use the same hook that you are using to transform the attrs in snake case with Ember.String.underscore and add the key that you want

http://www.emberjs.com.cn/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_underscore

you should also create a specific serializer for your model

`ember g serializer <name of your model>`

that way you change only the specific model that you want and not the whole application

Comment: Thanks, Marcell. I've used each of them before - but I guess I'm not thinking clearly! The JSONSerializer is working great. I can't really use the underscore method in this case. shippingStreetAddress ≠ shipping_to.address_line_1. And my serializer was already for 'order.'

Comment: If you feel like taking a stab at explaining what is happening in my example above - that would also be awesome.

Comment: I'm confused...so you _would_ use JSONapi serializer and not the JSON one?

Comment: happy to help :), you're forgetting the object format, json api object have a specific format, i've changed your example here: ember-twiddle.com/… but do not do this, use JSONSerializer instead so you don't need to delete any keys. obj: it was just a typo i had to repost it

Comment: : )   (Link is gone - but I got your points. + thanks for reminding me about bracket syntax - I barely ever use it and I forget it's there.)

Comment: link: https://ember-twiddle.com/7062d70d2eba3ba32a8f448cd50b2b2d, ember twiddle is a great place to test this kind of thing, i wish i knew how to better format the alertbox json message on chrome.

Comment: ^ This is really great. Thanks for your time. I like the alert before and after. : )